# Find the maximum occurance of a digit k in a given list of positive integers

Tags: dynamic-programming

Eg: k=2, arr[] = 13,12,242,32,1532,1222, 33
Output:3 (1222 has the most 2s, which is 3) 
How to solve with time compexity better than O(n²) i.e. two loops

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question. Please see: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Answer (score 0):

Well, to solve this problem we have to check all the digits of every number on the list.

So let's say the numbers have maximum_length = m, and we have a total of n numbers. Then we can achieve a complexity of O(n*m). Here is a sample c++ code, and here I am assuming that all numbers on the list fit on a 32 bit signed integer. It also produces the correct answer for the test case you have provided.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int calculate_ans( int number, int k ) {

    if( number == 0 ) {
        if( k == 0 ) return 1;
        return 0;
    }

    if( number < 0 ) number = -number;

    int ans = 0;

    while( number > 0 ) {
        int last_digit = ( number % 10 );
        if( last_digit == k ) ans++;
        number /= 10;
    }

    return ans;

}


int solve( const std::vector<int>& number_list, int k ) {
    int best = 0;
    for( const auto& number : number_list ) best = std::max( best, calculate_ans( number, k ) );
    return best;
}

int main() {
    std::vector< int > arr = { 13, 12, 242, 32, 1532, 1222, 33};
    std::cout << solve( arr, 2 ) << std::endl;
}
```